# Many errors only in Firefox

Tags: jquery

Hello I have different problem, because in Chrome, Opera and IE everything working good but in Firefox are many errors, TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function, timepicker is not a function, emojione is not a function, fullcalendar is not a function...
I am very confused because this problems are only in Firefox....

Thank you help and time :)

P.S.
Below my script list

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MyScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="AddFile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="AddMovie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Forms.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom\jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DatePicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-timepicker-master\jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"> </script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="PlacePicker.js"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="emojionearea-master\dist\emojionearea.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="EmojiPicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar-3.0.1\lib\moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar-3.0.1\fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar-3.0.1\locale-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Calendar.js"></script>

</head>


</html>
```

Comment: so make sure that all of those scripts are being loaded. if even one fails, then anything depending on it will ALSO fail.

Comment: Yes, I will check it but is this possible that is not working only in Firefox?

Comment: Are you loading two jQuery instances? 3.1.0 and 1.12.4?

Comment: @Sergiodiaz53 Yes he does ... PiotrS decide on which jquery version you want to use and remove the other. Then try again.